# How do I write a bash script to group together Rails log lines from parallel interleaved requests?

Tags: bash, text

Assuming that I have a list of Ruby on Rails 3 log files with the following filename format:

```
production.log.CCYYMMDD
```

I am using log tagging so all the lines are prefixed with the request-unique hash. Example:

```
[1a23f343a5331aeb03dc2461895d66d7] Completed 200 OK in 43.2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 25.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a] Started GET "/fp.js?_=1455251108526" for 27.55.132.119 at 2016-02-12 06:25:10 +0200
[d730a47ee957fb4b12b01c3b03357ba6] Started POST "/api/d" for 183.88.158.125 at 2016-02-12 06:25:10 +0200
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a] Processing by Api::DevicesController#fp as JS
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a]   Parameters: {"_"=>"1455251108526"}
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a]   Rendered api/devices/fp.js.erb (5.3ms)
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a] Completed 200 OK in 6.4ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

The case here is that a lot of processes are logging lines into the same file, which means that different request lines are interleaved to each other. You can see in the above example that the line for the request with id `d730a47ee957fb4b12b01c3b03357ba6` is in between the lines for the request with id `3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a`.

I wrote a Ruby script that would fix that, putting the same-request lines together, and in correct timestamp sequence. So, my Ruby script manages to process the above input and give:

```
[1a23f343a5331aeb03dc2461895d66d7] Completed 200 OK in 43.2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 25.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a] Started GET "/fp.js?_=1455251108526" for 27.55.132.119 at 2016-02-12 06:25:10 +0200
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a] Processing by Api::DevicesController#fp as JS
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a]   Parameters: {"_"=>"1455251108526"}
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a]   Rendered api/devices/fp.js.erb (5.3ms)
[3fb5d184493aea1f7637aa5a442d166a] Completed 200 OK in 6.4ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
[d730a47ee957fb4b12b01c3b03357ba6] Started POST "/api/d" for 183.88.158.125 at 2016-02-12 06:25:10 +0200
```

Is there a way that I can do that with standard bash commands?

Comment: Is that any different from sorting by the hash, and leaving the order as is for identical hashes?

Comment: Or are the hashes not lexically ordered?

Comment: If you just sort by hash, then sorting might change the order of the lines of the same request (same hash). I do not want that. For the same hash, the order should be preserved.

Comment: That can be done by stable sort, but my question was more if the order of first occurrences of each has is lexical (as in the example) or not.

Comment: No it's not. What do you mean about stable sort? Shall I Google for that? And if that is the answer, would you like to elaborate on that and submit a normal answer so that I can test and possible accept?

Comment: In the context of the GNU `sort` command, "stable" means just that if two sort keys are identical, their relative ordering is maintained, and without the "stable" option that's not guaranteed. That doesn't help here, though, as the first occurrence of keys isn't sorted lexically. I have an idea, though, I'll work on an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Example input

I've used this file as my sample input:

```
[abc1] Text abc_01
[abc1] Text abc_02
[def2] Text def_01
[abc1] Text abc_03
[def2] Text def_02
[def2] Text def_03
[xyz3] Text xyz_01
[abc1] Text abc_04
[xyz3] Text xyz_02
[def2] Text def_04
```

The first field acts as the hash, and the rest of the line is the log file entry.

The output we'd like to see:

```
[abc1] Text abc_01
[abc1] Text abc_02
[abc1] Text abc_03
[abc1] Text abc_04
[def2] Text def_01
[def2] Text def_02
[def2] Text def_03
[def2] Text def_04
[xyz3] Text xyz_01
[xyz3] Text xyz_02
```

Lines of the same hash are in the same order, but the hashes are now sorted by appearance.

#### Pure Bash solution

This is a *pure* Bash solution, using only built-ins:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read entire file into array
mapfile -t loglines < "$1"

# Associative array to map hashes to line numbers
declare -A hashes

# Array to keep track of sequence of hashes
declare -a hash_seq

# Current line number
ln_no=0

while read -r req_hash _; do
    if [[ -z ${hashes[$req_hash]} ]]; then # If we haven't seen this hash yet
        # Add hash to hash sequence
        hash_seq+=("$req_hash")
        # Add current line number as first line of hash
        hashes[$req_hash]=$ln_no
    else
        # Append current line number to hash
        hashes[$req_hash]+=" $ln_no"
    fi
    ((++ln_no)) # Increment line number
done < "$1"

# Loop over hashes in sequence
for i in "${hash_seq[@]}"; do
    # Loop over line number for each hash
    for ln in ${hashes[$i]}; do # Must not be quoted - shell word splitting!
        # Print next line for this hash
        echo "${loglines[$ln]}"
    done
done
```

I've added comments that should, I think, make it understandable what's happening:

- The whole file is read into an array first (the `mapfile` line).
- Then the whole file is traversed to find the sequence in which hashes occur (`hash_seq` array) and which line numbers belong to each hash (`hashes` associative array).
- Finally, we loop over all hashes in sequence, and for each hash over its line numbers, look that line up in the `loglines` array and print it.

This is quite slow, as we'll see later.

#### Bash with grep

If we don't restrict ourselves to just Bash, we don't have to store the whole file in an array and can use grep to extract the lines we want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Associative array to keep track of hashes seen
declare -A hashes

# Array to keep track of sequence of hashes
declare -a hash_seq

while read -r req_hash _; do
    if [[ -z ${hashes[$req_hash]} ]]; then # If we haven't seen this hash yet
        # Mark as "seen"
        hashes[$req_hash]=1
        # Add hash to hash sequence
        hash_seq+=("$req_hash")
    fi
done < "$1"

# Loop over hashes in sequence
for cur_hash in "${hash_seq[@]}"; do
    # Print all lines containing the hash
    grep -F "$cur_hash" "$1"
done
```

This does away with storing the file, the associative array and keeping track of the line numbers:

- The `while` loop gets the sequence in which the hashes appear.
- The `for` loop takes each hash, in sequence, and uses grep to get all the lines that are part of the corresponding request. The `-F` option was used so the square brackets are not interpreted as metacharacters.

#### An awk solution

Technically no longer "Bash", but usually available where Bash is.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    loglines[NR] = $0   # Store all lines
    if ($1 in hashes) { # Append line number if we've seen the hash before
        hashes[$1] = hashes[$1] " " NR
    }
    else {                      # New hash
        hashes[$1] = NR         # Add line number, mark as seen
        hash_seq[++ctr] = $1    # Add to hash sequence
    }
}

END {
    for (i = 1; i <= ctr; ++i) {                # Loop over hashes in sequence
        nl = split(hashes[hash_seq[i]], arr)    # Get line numbers
        for (j = 1; j <= nl; ++j)               # Loop over line numbers
            print loglines[arr[j]]              # Print corresponding line
    }
}
```

This works the same as the first Bash solution, but is much faster.

#### Benchmarking

What to choose? For the sample input expanded to 100,000 lines, the solutions fare as follows (output redirected to a file, as in `./SO.sh infile > outfile`):

- Pure Bash:

  ```
    real    1m7.021s
    user    1m2.265s
    sys     0m4.468s
  ```
- Bash and grep:

  ```
    real    0m3.882s
    user    0m1.967s
    sys     0m1.890s
  ```
- Awk:

  ```
    real    0m0.915s
    user    0m0.906s
    sys     0m0.015s
  ```

Unsurprisingly, awk is the fastest, but Bash with grep is not unbearably slow. Pure Bash *is* slow.

#### Limitations

Associative arrays were added in Bash 4.0, so the Bash solutions obviously require at least this version. I don't think I've used anything that's a GNU extension of either Bash, grep or awk, so these should be fairly portable.

Comment: I will accept this answer. But, neither pure bash solution, nor bash with grep worked for me. I am on Mac OS X Yosemite, but with upgraded bash to version `4.3.42`. On the other hand, the `awk` solution worked for me.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos How don't they work? Just wrong results, or error messages? I can't see what wouldn't work with a Bash 4.3 or a BSD sed.

Comment: For pure bash solution, the first 2 errors that I get are:
`./pure_bash_solution.sh: line 4: mapfile: command not found
./pure_bash_solution.sh: line 7: declare: -A: invalid option`
For grep solution I get :
`./grep_solution.sh: line 4: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
./grep_solution.sh: line 10: [abc1]: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[abc1]")`
Sorry, I didn't have time to search further and give you more information. Can you come out of something given the above?

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos `mapfile` and associative arrays were both introduced in Bash 4.0, so I don't understand why your Bash doesn't understand them if you have 4.3, as you say. Are you sure you're running these with Bash 4.3?

Comment: Ooooh. You are right. You have in your scripts the path to my old bash version. I need to update that to use the new version. Actually, I will create a link of /bin/bash to the path of the new version. Will let you know.